# Ubuntu Server Takes time to resolve website name but not IP address in wget command

Tags: 12.04, networking, dns

I have ubuntu server 12.04 LTS . When i fetch something over the internet using wget command. It easily starts when i give address like wget 100.100.100.100/index.html means ip address.
it immediately start downloading that thing.

But if i use wget www.google.com/index.html

It takes almost 10-15 seconds to resolve. I think the problem is with dns. It is resolving too late.

Can anyone help me what can be the problem.
My server is behind router and on NAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try using google DNS? Use 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as your primary DNS, and see whether it works better.